# Backbone.js validation broken (0.9.9 vs. 0.9.10)

Tags: backbone.js

Backbone changed a few things about validation between these versions, first off, you now have to explicitly pass {validation: true} with a set call for validation to trigger. There must have been another change too, because this doesn't work no longer.

```
model.set(obj, {
    error : function(model, error){
        //Do stuff with error
    }
})
```

I found this ticket on backbone's github, but it only answers the issue if using save, not set.

https://github.com/jashkenas/backbone/issues/2153

Comment: The same applies for `set` also. The `error` callback no longer triggered instead of you should use the `"invalid"` event `model.on("invalid", function(model, error) {
  alert(error);
});`

Answer (score 0):

Here's the solution I've discovered.

1) Assign the set to a variable called success (or whatever you like)

```
var success = model.set(obj, {validate : true});
```

2) Check the status of success, and then use `model.validationError`

```
if(!success){
    var error = model.validationError;
    // Do stuff with error
}
```